# Heroku ps:exec won't connect

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'm quite a newbie on heroku. So, sorry for the silly question.
My problem is, I don't know what is the error, but one thing for sure I couldn't connect through ssh to my heroku server. If possible I would like to know how to get more detailed error log or something like that. I've tried adding `-v` or `--verbose` switch to `heroku` command but no luck.

Bellow is the complete action I did, well, Basically I followed what is written in the heroku's site.

Here's how to connect through ssh  according to heroku's tutorial site.

> ```
> xxx@yyy:~/xwprog/heroku-sample-gradle1
> $ heroku ps:exec
> Establishing credentials... done
> Connecting to web.1 on ⬢ guarded-fjord-42322...
>  ▸    There was an error connecting to the dyno!
> ```

---

process currently running

> ```
> xxx@yyy:~/xwprog/heroku-sample-gradle1
> $ heroku ps
> Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
> For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping
>
> === web (Free): build/install/gradle-getting-started/bin/gradle-getting-started (1)
> web.1: up 2018/03/10 16:56:04 +0700 (~ 16m ago)
> ```

---

Tried to run bash, but it's actually work. The downside was each time I disconnected from it, the state also got reset, and prone to get disconnected, with error message `ECONNRESET: read ECONNRESET`

> ```
> xxx@yyy:~/xwprog/heroku-sample-gradle1
> $ heroku run bash
> Running bash on ⬢ guarded-fjord-42322... up, run.3587 (Free)
> ~ $
> ```

---

Thank you.